# The database schema is not in sync with the current mapping file

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine, symfony5

I'm working with Symfony 5, and got some issues with my migrations.

I created my model properly, all the migrations passed.

Just to check I run : `./bin/console doctrine:schema:vaidate`

which tell me that the mapping is ok, but for the db :

```
The database schema is not in sync with the current mapping file.
```

So I run `./bin/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql` to see what I've missed and it gives me :

```
ALTER TABLE user CHANGE orders_id orders_id INT DEFAULT NULL;
ALTER TABLE user CHANGE cart_id cart_id INT DEFAULT NULL; 
ALTER TABLE USER CHANGE roles roles JSON NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE characteristic CHANGE color color VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL;
```

The thing is that at no point I've asked for those changes, and they don't seem to make sense as we change color to color for example.

I've tried cleanning the cache :

```
 ./bin/console cache:clear 
 ./bin/console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata
 ./bin/console doctrine:cache:clear-query
 ./bin/console doctrine:cache:clear-result
```

and run schema validate command but the output is still the same.

I've also tried generating the migration for those changes with `./bin/console d:m:diff`, and then execute this migrations, it executes well but  `doctrine:schema:validate`  still gives me an error.

I've also updated my server_version in `doctrine.yaml` and `.env` file, as the default is 5.7 and I'm using mariadb 10.3

Does anyone have any idea on what I'm missing ? Thanks for your help

My config `.env` file :

```
 ###> doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###
 # Format described at https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/configuration.html#connecting-using-a-url
 # For an SQLite database, use: 
 "sqlite:///%kernel.project_dir%/var/data.db"
 # For a PostgreSQL database, use: 
 "postgresql://db_user:db_password@127.0.0.1:5432/db_name serverVersion=11&charset=utf8"
 # IMPORTANT: You MUST configure your server version, either here or in config/packages/doctrine.yaml
 DATABASE_URL=mysql://root:@mariadb:3306/ecommerce_db?serverVersion=10.3
 ###< doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###
```

and `doctrine.yaml` :

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
        server_version: '10.3'
    
        # IMPORTANT: You MUST configure your server version,
        # either here or in the DATABASE_URL env var (see .env file)
        #server_version: '5.7'
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: true
        naming_strategy: 
doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore_number_aware
        auto_mapping: true
        mappings:
            App:
                is_bundle: false
                type: annotation
                dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity'
                prefix: 'App\Entity'
                alias: App
```

Field that cause issue on User entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Order", inversedBy="users")
 */
private $orders;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Cart", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 */
private $cart;
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="json")
 */
private $roles = [];
```

And from Characteristic entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
 * @Groups({"product.read"})
 */
private $color;
```

UPDATE:

I've also tried :

dump the db : `./bin/console d:d:d --force`

clean all caches:

```
 ./bin/console cache:clear 
 ./bin/console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata
 ./bin/console doctrine:cache:clear-query
 ./bin/console doctrine:cache:clear-result
```

recreate db : `./bin/console d:d:c`

Clean migrations, keep only tables creation and relaunch all with :

```
 ./bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate
```

Still get the same error message

Comment: It is changing the defaults, not the field names. I suspect you're something wrong with the annotations/xml files. Could you please edit the question with all these informations?

Comment: I've updated with two db config files, tell me if you need something else

Comment: Show us how the entities are annotated or configured via xml/yaml. Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to `server_version: mariadb-10.3`. Check de docs https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html and serch for `server_version` and check the note

Comment: Yes I've tried mariadb-10.3 it does not change the outcome